# libxml++/libxml++.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I am using ubuntu 12.4 g++ i'm working on `libxml++` library I have included this library in my program but I am getting an error saying

```
libxml++/libxml++.h: No such file or directory
```

i also tried compiling using  `g++ main.cc -o main pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6` but it is not working. I have installed the latest libraries using `sudo apt-get install libxml++`.

Comment: What's the output of pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6 ?

Comment: Just look in your include directory where libxml++.h is. It obviously isn't in the path you try to include.

Comment: Output is something like this.   s$ g++ main.cc -o main pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6
g++: error: pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: libxml++-2.6: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--cflags’
g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--libs’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While compiling for libxml we have to use these options. `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6`  this should be in single quotation mark / Backticks ("`", grave accents), .

So the command should be like this.

```sh
$ g++ main.cc -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6`
```

or go through this once. http://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/stable/

Comment: Backticks ("`", grave accents), *not* single quotation marks.